# How to Make This Section Responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have tried many things with `max-width`, `width:auto`.

But can't get it to work after 2 hours.

Test
    
        
    
        
            
                0
            
        
        
            
                0
            
        
        
            
                0 
            
        
        
            
                0
            
        
        
            
                0
            
        
        
            
                0
            
        
        
            
                0
            
        
        
             
                0

```
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="">
            <img alt="AWESOME!" src="/v1/72x72/1f44f.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">AWESOME!</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="nice&amp;28">
            <img alt="NICE!" src="/v1/72x72/1f60f.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">NICE!</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="loved&amp;28">
            <img alt="LOVED!" src="/v1/72x72/1f60d.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">LOVED!</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="lol&amp;28" >
            <img alt="LOL!" src="/v1/72x72/1f606.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">LOL!</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="funny&amp;28">
            <img alt="FUNNY" src="/v1/72x72/1f602.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">FUNNY</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="fail&amp;28">
            <img alt="FAIL!" src="/v1/72x72/1f44e.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">FAIL!</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="omg&amp;28">
            <img alt="OMG" src="/v1/72x72/1f601.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">OMG</span></a></div>
    <div class="reaction-emoji"><a class="postable" data-method="Post" data-target="reactions" href="ew&amp;28">
            <img alt="EW" src="/v1/72x72/1f616.png" width="46">
            <span class="text">EW</span></a></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyoqk2n9/

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem!

Comment: i cant make this whole div responsive. You can see at http://jsfiddle.net/hyoqk2n9/. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You need to use media queries. You can read about them at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).